# restricting the number of docker containers that can be created from an image

Tags: image, docker, containers

Can we restrict the number of docker containers created from an image ?

For example, lets us take I have an image name called "myuser/XYZ", the number of containers that can be instantiated should be 10. So system should not allow when the user tries to instantiate the 11th container based on that image.

Comment: you can check with `docker ps -q -f "ancestor=$IMAGE" | wc -l` the number of running containers from that image, and if your user is in a script, you can allow him to launch a new one only if he is within limits

Comment: This will certainly work when the container creation is done via a script. But how can we do this when i run docker commands directly to create container.

Say 11th time I try to do a "docker run..." and it fails saying limit exceeded.

Comment: you need to add a qualifier to `docker run` such as /maximum_container and do the check inside docker...